# Ebay public key verification in fails in C# but works in node

Tags: c#, ebay-api, ecdsa

I've been attempting to verify ebay notifications in C# .net core 3.1 but it rejects the signature.

I have a working, minimal example in node. Note that I've had to redact the body content. The signature verifies OK.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const validateSignature = (message, signature, publicKey) => {

    const verifier = crypto.createVerify('ssl3-sha1');

    verifier.update(JSON.stringify(message));

    return verifier.verify(`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${publicKey}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`, signature, "base64");
};

const BODY = "redacted";
const SIG = `MEUCIG9ANqAZ3MIS6CDNcJFf/5d8VlIyHuHZlgw57HLzALl+AiEA0Egsw0y7VLvsUxKhBhivVr/Ee6O69lmkIchftQ2Fnqs=`;
const KEY = `MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEZhhxXKtR+TOvtDbgTPCkSof02qgBB7IsYOyf76ilExJ/upAa/vKIKheOoCyOpcLmi4t0b4uepb7LLjmMr90FUg==`;

try {
    const result = validateSignature(BODY, SIG, KEY);
   
    console.log("verification: ", result);   
} catch(Err) {
    console.error(Err);
}
```

This returns true.

Here is the same example, in .net core 3.1, again, the content is redacted

```cs
class Program
{
    public static bool ValidateEcdsa(string bodyData, string signature, string keyString)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create())
            {
                var contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyData);

                var signatureBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature ?? "");

                var keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(keyString);

                ecdsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keyBytes, out _);

                bool success = ecdsa.VerifyData(contentBytes, signatureBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1);

                return success;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static string BODY = "redacted";
    public static string SIG = "MEUCIG9ANqAZ3MIS6CDNcJFf/5d8VlIyHuHZlgw57HLzALl+AiEA0Egsw0y7VLvsUxKhBhivVr/Ee6O69lmkIchftQ2Fnqs=";
    public static string KEY = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEZhhxXKtR+TOvtDbgTPCkSof02qgBB7IsYOyf76ilExJ/upAa/vKIKheOoCyOpcLmi4t0b4uepb7LLjmMr90FUg==";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = ValidateEcdsa(BODY, SIG, KEY);
        Console.WriteLine($"verification: {result}");
    }
}
```

This will load the public key info without exceptions, but returns false.

What is different between the .net example and the node example?

### A note on begin and end headers

the node library wants the `---begin---` and `---end---` headers. Without this it fails.
The .net library will not import the key if you have these headers, hence they have been removed for this minimal example.

### Are the bodies the same?

I can't show the original bodies and had to redact them here. However, I have used sha1 hashes to ensure they are the same exact strings in both minimal examples.

node:

```js
var shasum = crypto.createHash('sha1')
shasum.update(BODY)
console.log("hash of body data", shasum.digest('hex'))
```

.net:

```cs
using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
{
    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    var sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length * 2);

    foreach (byte b in hash)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Both of these give the same identical hash sequence.

Comment: If you base64 decode the bit between the ---BEGIN--- and ---END--- headers you should get a byte array of valid ASN.1.

Comment: Surely it is, otherwise it would be closed rather than downvoted. You have a base64-encoded key. You are trying to get its bytes in utf8 (why utf8 specifically of all the possibilities?) and pass it to `ImportRSAPublicKey` even though it [specifically says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importrsapublickey?view=net-5.0#remarks) *"If the value is Base64-encoded or in the PEM text format, the caller must Base64-decode the contents before calling this method"*. That would be lack of research.

Comment: How do you pass the key into the function? It seems you need to extract it from between BEGIN and END markers and decode base64.

Comment: I'll try a few mor ethings after removing the begin and end (although thats on the list of things I tried already, both with DecodeBase64, UTF8.GetBYtes and ASCII.GetBytes

Comment: That's not the complete key, though, is it? That's far too small. Where did you get the certificate from? Can you try parsing it with `openssl rsa -in <filename>` or e.g. pasting it into an online parser e.g. [here](https://8gwifi.org/PemParserFunctions.jsp)

Comment: @Rup the certificate is from ebay. Their API for public keys (they use public key signing for their notifications API)
are you saying that you think ebay are giving us the wrong key?

Comment: @GSerg "lack of research" is not correct. what you're describing is on the list of things I've tried.

Comment: I don't think the key you've pasted into the question is a valid key, no (and the online parser I linked to rejects it too). If you were just giving us a few example lines from a larger base64 key then that would make sense. If you were trying to give us the whole key then it looks wrong to me. Is that key public e.g. can you point us to somewhere in the developer documentation where we'd find it? Or did they email it to you? (I'd expect the real key to have more linebreaks too)

Comment: THe api is here. you can see what it returns from the example. It does look too small, but i dont know what exactly it contains. https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/notification/resources/public_key/methods/getPublicKey

Comment: That's not an RSA key, that's an ECDSA key - the 'algorithm' value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234827/discussion-between-speciesunknown-and-rup).

Comment: The key is to be imported with [`ECDsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=netcore-3.1) (after removing header, footer, line breaks and Base64 decoding of the rest), because it has the X.509/SPKI format.

Comment: Besides the problem with the key import, a UTF8 encoding of the signature is also wrong (more likely is a Base64 decoding).  Also note that EC has two signature formats (r|s and ASN.1). `ECDsa#VerifyData()` expects the r|s format.

Comment: We've been trying ECDSA instead. its better but won't verify the signature.

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong. I used an Ebay test notification and an ECDSA test key and was able to verify successfully. You should post some test data and the code you used for verification.

Comment: @user9014097 Its clear that I'm doing something wrong. What language are you working with?

Comment: @user9014097 note that I already put sample data in the question. Although I had to redact the body.

Comment: C#. By test data I mean key, signature and message to be verified. Everything unchanged, so that verification is definitely possible. Please note that even the slightest change (you're talking about redaction somewhere) in the message prevents verification.

Comment: @user9014097 i can only give you my assurance that I used the exact same string in the node example as in the C# example.

Comment: @user9014097 I used sha1 to ensure that what I just said was true. I know that both bodies are identical.

Answer (score 4):

### the .net ECDsa library defaults to IEEE P1363 but ebay are using RFC 3279

### You need .net core 5.0.

Then you can simply pass an optional parameter to the VerifyData method.

```cs
bool success = ecdsa.VerifyData(contentBytes, signatureBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, DSASignatureFormat.Rfc3279DerSequence);
```

The node version is automatically choosing RFC 3279.

### Alternatively you can use [BouncyCastle.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.NetCore)

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;


static bool VerifyData(string bodyData, string signature, string keyString)
{
    var pubkeyString = $"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n{keyString}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    var data = bodyData;
    var signatureBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

    var pemreader = new PemReader(new StringReader(pubkeyString));
    var pubkey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemreader.ReadObject();

    // Verify using the public key
    var signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withECDSA");
    signer.Init(false, pubkey);
    signer.BlockUpdate(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length);
    var success = signer.VerifySignature(signatureBytes);

    return success;
}
```

This supports .net standard 2.0 and is compatible with most versions of .net  framework and .net core.

Comment: For lower versions than .NET 5, the conversion from ASN.1/DER to r|s (or from RFC 3279 format to IEEE P1363) can also be done/implemented by yourself. It is not very complex and is described in detail [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1797).

Comment: @user9014097 im not sure if that will work if we're being given a signature and public key by a third party. but an easier solution was to use a better library

Comment: A signature in ASN.1/DER format can always be converted to the r|s format (and vice versa). But of course it is easier to use a library that supports both formats or the conversion (e.g. BouncyCastle).

Comment: @user9014097 could you post an answer with some code to perform the conversion?

Comment: `r` and `s` are contained in the ASN.1 signature. [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1797) you can find a simple description of the ASN.1 format, from which the positions and lengths of `r` and `s` can be seen. After extracting `r` and `s` (and removing a possible sign byte) they only need to be concatenated: `r|s`. If I find time and nobody beats me, I will post an implementation.

Comment: @user9014097 doesn't the RFC version have a variable signature, while the IEEE has a fixed signature? How is it possible for one to be valid in the context of the other?

Comment: With ASN.1 there is a fluctuation  of the size, because of the possible sign bytes or because leading 0x00 are omitted for shorter keys. But this is exactly defined, so there is no contradiction to the fixed length of the r|s format.

Comment: Could you please specify exactly which NuGet you use, and what version?

Comment: @ClausAppel Did you still need an answer? I would use the latest package, I don't recall now exactly which version I was using.

Comment: I suggest that you update the answer to at least include the NAME of the NuGet you used. There is more than one BouncyCastle NuGet out there.

Comment: @ClausAppel I found which one it was